# How to find the variance of several images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am relatively new to MATLAB and Image processing, so understand with me. I am working in experiment on image processing, and my current stage, I need to 
1) read some images (about 100 images of same dimension)
2) store them in a variable (either cell array, vector or structure)
3) Find the variance of each pixel in each image
4) Form a new matrix to store each computed variance

Here is my code, but I am not sure it solves this problem not withstanding that I get result

```
clc;
im_File = dir('*.bmp');
files = {im_File.name};

for k=1:numel(files)

   im{k}  = imread(files{k});

   %# Get the number of dimensions for your arrays 
   dim = ndims(im{k});                    

   all_images = cat(dim+1,im{:});

   % Use linear combine to acquire all the images
   Linear_comb_im = imlincomb(1,all_images,'uin'); 

   %get the variance of all images
   computed_variance = var(double(Linear_comb_im),1,dim+1); 

end
```

Comment: Why are you calling `imlincomb`? You should just be able to concatenate along `dim+1` like you've done (although move that outside of the loop) and compute variance along the `dim+1` dimension (as you've done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that you have a redundant variable here  : both `im` and `all_im` basically save the same information. if the dimensions werent the same i would use a cell array, otherwise matlab likes matrices better.

In addition, I am not sure why you are performing the linear combination.

I would do the following:

```
clc;
im_File = dir('*.bmp');
files = {im_File.name};

for k=1:numel(files)

   im(:,:,k)  = imread(files{k}); % to save time you should initialize im begore the loop i.e. im = zeros(m,n,numerl(files)), where m,n are the size of the images

end

%get the variance of all images
computed_variance = var(double(im),1,3);
```

so `im` here is a 3D matrix containing the images in the 3rd dimension. In order to access the idx image:

```
im(:,:,idx)
```